# XML validation does not release the xml file

Tags: java, xml, validation

I'm trying to validate an XML file against an XSD file in JAVA. My problem is not the validation itself, since this is working fine.
My problem is, that the XMLfile is not released after the validation. If I'm trying to access the file afterwards, I get the error "The file is used by another resource".

This error only happens, when the validation fails (an exception is trown from the validator.validate(xmlSource);)
If the file is validated without problems, the file is released and can be accessed by others.

Any idears?

```
public void validateXMLAgainstXSD(String xmlPath, String xsdPath) throws ParserException, IOException
  {
    Source xmlSource = null;
    File schemaFile = null;
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = null;
    Schema schema = null;
    Validator validator = null;
    try 
    {
      schemaFile = new File(xsdPath);
      xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath));
      schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
      schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
      validator = schema.newValidator();
      validator.validate(xmlSource);
    }
    catch (SAXException e)
    {
      //_log.error("ParsingDataFile: XML file could not be validated against XSD file: XML File=<", xmlFile.getAbsolutePath(), "> XSD file=<", xsdFile.getAbsolutePath(), ">. Exception=<", e, ">");
      xmlSource = null;
      schemaFile = null;
      schemaFactory = null;
      schema = null;
      validator.reset();
      validator = null;      
      //throw new ParserException(-1, ParserException.ERROR_CODE_XML_NOT_VALID, e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you 'trying to access the file afterwards'?

Comment: You always have to close opened resources or most of the time. I don't see you using any `finally` block.

Comment: @LutzHorn I try to move the file from one directory to another. But the solution provided by Rafik991 solved my problem.

Comment: @Omoro Yes, if I had opened anything, I would need to close it. The problem is, that there is nothing to close.. But the solution by Rafik991 solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to create StreamSource using constructor with inputstream.

like that

```
 InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(xmlPath));
    source = new StreamSource(inputStream);
```

and then in your method use finally statement

```
finally{
inputStream.close();
}
```

But remember to be sure that you initialize your stream before you go to finally block or simply catch exception thrown by closing not initialized or opened inputStream.

Comment: The processor SHOULD close the stream when you call it with the "new File" constructor, but it looks as if it isn't doing so. This suggestion might provide a workaround. But I would add a SystemId to the StreamSource constructor so that the base URI of the document is known.

Answer (score 0):

RMachnik is right, worked like a charm!

Also can use `TryWithResources`:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    ...
    new StreamSource(inputStream);
    ...
}
```